# Toolbar, Toggle во фрагментах

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть `main_activity.xml`, который является контейнером для фрагментов.
Во всех фрагментах я планирую использовать табы с другими фрагментами.

Как лучше инициализировать `ToolBar` и `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, в самих фрагментах, или в `MainActivity`?

В данный момент, приложение крашится (лог ниже).
Если закомментировать строки:

```
initTogle(rootView, activity); 
initTabs(rootView);
```

то приложение запустится, но всё равно вылетит лог с ошибкой.(лог ниже).

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        startFragment1();


    }



    private void startFragment1() {

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Fragment1(getSupportFragmentManager(), this))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    }

}
```

**Fragment1**

```
package ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    FragmentManager fm;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Activity activity;


    public Fragment1(FragmentManager fm, Activity activity) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.fm = fm;

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);


       initToolbar(rootView);


      initTogle(rootView, activity);

        initTabs(rootView);


        return rootView;


    }

private void initToolbar(View rootView) {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment1");
}



    private void initTogle(View rootView, Activity activity) {




        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle togle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                activity,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.open,
                R.string.close
        );

        togle.syncState();

    }

    private void initTabs(View rootView) {

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(fm);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"


       />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"



        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_fragment1.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


      <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight = "6dp"

            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"


        />



</FrameLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"


        />
```

**Лог(без инициализации  тулбара и тогла через фрагмент. Приложение запускается)**

```
07-06 11:01:55.453 18604-18604/ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler/ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:431)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1952)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:144)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:307)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:81)
                                                                                   at ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1; no empty constructor
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:420)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1952) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:144) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:307) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:81) 
                                                                                   at ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Лог с инициализацией тулбара и тогла (приложение крашится)**

```
07-06 11:05:47.613 19933-19933/ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler/ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:431)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1952)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:144)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:307)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:81)
                                                                                   at ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.Fragment1; no empty constructor
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:420)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1952) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:144) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:307) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:81) 
                                                                                   at ru.alexbykov.fragmentexampler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы приложили тип ошибки и стакТрасе и точную строку где ошибка. И лучше не делать фрагменты вложенными и заменить их на активити

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил логи и строки, на которых вылетает ошибка.
 Почему лучше использовать активити? у меня 3 совершенно одинаковых окна планируется, с разными табами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб +, в каждом активити придётся тогда создавать NavigationView..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В вашей ошибке дословно сказано, что фрагмент должен иметь пустой, публичный конструктор. У вас же он не пустой. Не надо передавать что-то во фрагменты/активити через конструктор. Лучше вообще считать, что у этих классов конструктора нет.
2. Передавать значения во фрагменты надо через Bundle, передаваемый через метод `setArguments(Bundle args)`.
3. Получать ссылку на активити надо в методе `onAttach()` методом `getActivity()` или в нём же скастовав `Context` к `Activity`.
4. `FragmentManager` получайте в нужный момент просто вызовом `getSupportFragmentManager()`
5. Фрагменты, вложенные во фрагменте - ситуация ведущая ко множеству багов. Лучше не пробовать так делать. Если вам надо отображать фрагменты во `ViewPager` то сделайте по активити на каждый `ViewPager`. Если при этом нужен `NavigationDrawer`, то сделайте базовую активити с его реализацией и последующие активити от неё наследуйте.